# What information needs to be hidden before pushing my project to github

Tags: git, github, flask

I have built a basic website using Flask framework. I now want to push this to my github account but I am aware certain data needs to be hidden. It is a bare-bone website and contains no payment channels tied to it. What information and files need to be hidden (using gitignore or any other way) before safely uploading to github.

Comment: Why don't you create a private repository?

Comment: @RonanBoiteau  i don't want to spend money as I am just trying to learn.

Comment: Private repositories have been free since January 2019.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ready `.gitignore` configs:

## Python.gitignore

[gitignore/Python.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore) from great [github/gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore) collection having almost 90k GitHub stars

[Flask section](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore#L63) contains two lines:

> ```
> # Flask stuff:
> instance/
> .webassets-cache
> ```

## Flask config example

[flask_config_example/.gitignore](https://github.com/MirelaI/flask_config_example/blob/master/.gitignore) by [MirelaI](https://github.com/MirelaI)

It contains only one line:

> ```
> config.json
> ```